# Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module" in Ubuntu 18,04

Tags: gtk, c

This seems to be a recurring problem in ubuntu. I am running ubuntu 18.04 and can not seem to get around this GTK 3 problem.
I have run `sudo ldconfig -v` even after performing

```
sudo link libcanberra-gtk3-module.so canberra-gtk-module.so
```

to create a link in the `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/modules` directory for the file that the loader is looking for. All with no luck. No GTK3 C program will load and execute properly unless this error is cleared. Any other suggestions?

```
ls -al /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/modules
total 64 
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 22 16:01 . 
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Aug 1 2017 .. 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Dec 3 2017 canberra-gtk-module.so -> libcanberra-gtk3-module.so 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 26536 Dec 3 2017 libcanberra-gtk3-module.so 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Dec 3 2017 libcanberra-gtk-module.so -> libcanberra-gtk3-module.so 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 27296 Dec 1 2017 libunity-gtk-module.so
```

The gtk3-demo bash command executing from its directory produces the same error. I guess this is as simple a reproduction as can be possibly communicated and replicated. I need to understand the object code load function and why this error occurs for GTK3 C compiled code or any code loaded for execution. This seems like such a simple install error one can fall into and not understand what failed and how to correct it...

---------- 26 April 2019 -----
Back to working on this...
The canberra-gtk-module is found in the following directory and is in the default load library list. 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/modules
dynamic linker failure??

---------- 28 April 2019 ------------
~/Downloads/gtk+-3.22.30/demos/gtk-demo$ gtk3-demo
Is probably the best method to show this error. When loading the demo provided the [Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"] appears in the terminal console log but the application window presented appears OK. Running the screen selection "Application Class" presents the same error to the terminal console log. However, running the screen selection "Assistant" does not produce the terminal console log message and the GTK screen appears without error. The dynamic link loader "ld.so" can not successfully link load the canberra-gtk-module with the GTK version 3.22.30 code provided.

Comment: Please provide more details - which application you are trying to launch? How did you installed it? What is your desktop environment? Is it clean install or upgrade from previous release? Please add output of `ls -al /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/modules` to the question.

Comment: Here is :ls -al /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/modules
total 64
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Apr 22 16:01 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Aug  1  2017 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    26 Dec  3  2017 canberra-gtk-module.so -> libcanberra-gtk3-module.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 26536 Dec  3  2017 libcanberra-gtk3-module.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    26 Dec  3  2017 libcanberra-gtk-module.so -> libcanberra-gtk3-module.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 27296 Dec  1  2017 libunity-gtk-module.so

Comment: Clean install of new Ubuntu system. Using any example of "hello world" written in C and using GTK3 you can imagine. GCC to compile and then ./helloworld to load and execute. I get the load errors but the hello world box is displayed - but not as it should be...

Comment: Still too vague. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1136139/edit) your question with complete step-by-step guide to make your problem reproducible. Do you have any problems with `gtk-3-demo` application?

Answer (score 3):

Using 20.04. Min install. Installing `libcanberra-gtk` resolved this issue for me.

```bsh
sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module
```