# How to fix error: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

Tags: gtk, matlab

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and when I launch MATLAB R2019b I get the following error:

`Gtk-Message: 00:20:10.283: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
[0921/002013.995543:INFO:context.cpp(159)] Using multi-threaded message loop for Linux`

I read this thread: [Failed to load module “canberra-gtk-module” .... but already installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342202/failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module-but-already-installed)

but wasn't able to resolve the issue. Matlab launches and then it functions well but I would like to solve this error. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: It may be caused by 32-bit versions of the libraries. Try `sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 libcanberra-gtk3-module:i386`.

Comment: Actually, this didn't resolve the issue. It still persists.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not a an issue unique to Matlab, but Ubuntu. It is solved by [executing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1136139/failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module-in-ubuntu-18-04):

- `sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module`

Answer (score 4):

So the answer is in a terminal excecute the following

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk* libgconf-2-4
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so /usr/lib/libcanberra-gtk-module.so
```

The second line will create a link to the module. Matlab works with gtk-2.0 module. For other linux distributions [follow this.](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/remove-canberra-gtk-module-and-pk-gtk-module-messages.html#)
Problem solved, at least for me.

Comment: The additional `libgconf-2-4` was needed to get chromium working