# Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module" while launching OpenVPN

Tags: apt, package-management, 22.04, openvpn

I just installed both Ubuntu (22.04) and OpenVPN. But when I try to launch OpenVPN, I get what looks like a recurring Ubuntu issue : Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module".
I've looked a lot of posts here and their answers but nothing has done the trick for me :

- [Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208431/failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module) and its solutions : `sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module` and `sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386`
- [Failed to load module “canberra-gtk-module” .... but already installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342202/failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module-but-already-installed) and its solutions : `sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module` and `udo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module` or even `sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386`
- [Failed to load module 'canberra-gtk-module' proxychains](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1306558/failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module-proxychains) and its solutions `sudo snap remove --purge firefox` and `sudo apt install firefox`
- [Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module" in Ubuntu 18,04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1136139/failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module-in-ubuntu-18-04)

The only things that I didn't dare to try for now are `sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk*` and `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libcanberra-gtk-module` given the warnings.

I'd be glad if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of installing the cranberra gtk module, it should work fine to install the default module.

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install libgtk-3-dev
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the error message is still here.